# How to attach another component to a ComponentType?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Is there a way to attach another component to a component that's already been typed as a ComponentType?

E.g:

```
type Props = {
  name: string,
}

const Header: ComponentType<Props> = ({ props }) => (<h1>{name}</h1>)
const SubHeader: ComponentType<Props> = ({ props }) => (<h2>{name}</h2>)

Header.SubHeader = SubHeader // this is causes a flow error due to ComponentType
```

The example is a bit contrived, but the manual forcing to `ComponentType` is sometimes necessary when using HOCs or `styled-components`.

Comment: Could you [extend the type of `Header` using intersection types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582880/flow-create-a-flow-type-by-extending-another-type)?

Comment: Yeah, intersection will do the job: `const Header: ComponentType<Props> & { SubHeader?: ComponentType<Props> }`

Comment: Hmm, I think this would usually work but using `styled-components` breaks it since their definition of `styled()` rejects all intersection types. I'll ask them what to do about this, but this is answered :). Do either of you want to answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intersection will do the job: `const Header: ComponentType<Props> & { SubHeader: ComponentType<Props> }`.

Note that `SubHeader` must not be a `Maybe` or optional type, as Flow will complain if you try to render a `Maybe` or optional type as a component.